# How can I move a Firefox snap user profile back to its original place in the home directory?

Tags: firefox

For a technical reason, I had to switch from Firefox snap back to the traditional Firefox. I used [that straightforward guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/835198) to accomplish that step.

I then realised that the Firefox snap (installed when I changed to 22.04 a few months ago) moved my original Firefox profile from my home (`~/.mozilla`) to the snap folder (`~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla`). Upon the required removal of the snap package, my profile (even without using `--purge`) actually was removed as well. I thought there was something wrong but it seems to be the normal behavior of `snap remove ...`. Although I managed to restore my Firefox profile from `/var/lib/snapd/snapshots` (with `snap restore ...`) and to copy it manually to `~/.mozilla`, starting the traditional Firefox does not seem to make use of that copied profile anymore. I'm used to copying Firefox profiles but here it failed for a reason that is not obvious to me.

Switching back to Firefox snap brings me back to a working configuration. But that is unfortunately not what I want. What do I need to take into account when copying my profile from `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla` back to `~/.mozilla` and use the Firefox deb package?

Comment: If you copy only a profile it will not be used unless you go to `about:profiles` and choose it to be used. Or copy the whole `.mozilla`-folder from `~/snap/firefox/common/` to `~/`.

Comment: (as requested by the OP). Under 20.04 and earlier versions I created a Firefox account. We I first loaded 22.04 with the snap version, I logged in to my FF account and all my stuff was immediately available. I since changed 22.04 back to the APT version, logged in to my FF account as before and all was well with the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure no instance of Firefox is running and move the `.mozilla` folder under `~/snap/firefox/common/` to your home folder.

In recent versions of Firefox, a different install (i.e. the Mozilla APT version instead of the snap) will not automatically pick up your existing profile. First time after the move, start the profile manager (`firefox --ProfileManager`) and select your profile.

Comment: Thx, @vanadium. This saved my life :)

Comment: Sure, done now :)